# Firebase cloud functions errors: CORS and Unhandled error TypeError: openai is not a constructor at GPT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, openai-api

I'm trying to make a https onCall to the OpenAi API using a firebase cloud function. At first I got a CORS error, which seems to be resolved, after changing this:

`exports.GPT = functions.https.onCall((GPT));`

to this:

```
exports.GPT = functions.https.onCall(GPT, (req, res) => {
    // Set CORS headers for preflight requests
    // Allows GETs from any origin with the Content-Type header
    // and caches preflight response for 3600s

    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        // Send response to OPTIONS requests
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
        res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
        res.status(204).send('');
    } else {
        // Call GPT function
        GPT(req.body)
            .then((result) => {
                // Send response with result
                res.send(result);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // Send error response
                res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
            });
    }
});
```

Once I implement the CORS handling I get this error in the firebase console for the function: Unhandled error TypeError: openai is not a constructor at GPT

The GPT should work, it works on the client, in Reactjs, and looks like this in node.js:

```
const config = {
    apiKey: functions.config().openaikey
};

const GPT = async ({ split }) => {
    const openai = require('openai');
    const uuid = require('uuid');
    const uuidv4 = uuid.v4;

    const openaiapi = new openai(config.apiKey);

    try {
        if (split.length > 200) {
            console.log("turbo");
            const response = await openaiapi.createChatCompletion({
                model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
                messages: GPT35TurboMessage,
            });
            const newText = response.data.choices[0].message.content;
        } else {
            console.log("davinci");
            const prompt = split;
            const response = await openaiapi.createCompletion({
                model: "text-davinci-003",
                prompt: prompt,
                max_tokens: 1000,
            });
            const newText = response.data.choices[0].text;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }

}
```

I've tried moving:

```
    const openai = require('openai');
    const uuid = require('uuid');
    const uuidv4 = uuid.v4;

    const openaiapi = new openai(config.apiKey);
```

to above the function, which makes no difference.

I've also tried reinstalling openai with npm install openai, both in my project path and the functions path, which makes no difference.

I've also tried updating package.json and package-lock.json to include the current version of openai.

Comment: `functions.https.onCall` doesn't work the way you expect.  It's not used for making a request, it's used for handling incoming requests to a function you define, typically coming from a related web or mobile application.  If you are not trying to handle requests from an app, then Cloud Functions is probably not the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Doug:

> `functions.https.onCall` doesn't work the way you expect. It's not used for making a request, it's used for handling incoming requests to a function you define, typically coming from a related web or mobile application. If you are not trying to handle requests from an app, then Cloud Functions is probably not the right tool for this job.

You can check this documentation on [calling functions from your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding all of this... How would I go about making it so the user calls something on the backend that handles everything with the OpenAI API and returns the string it generates, so I don't expose the API key to the user?